# batch or chunk for python dataframe

Tags: python

I'm working on a project with a dataframe (30000 rows & 2 columns) and I want to create a loop or a batch to feed my classifier with a specific size every time. 
For example first time I'll train with 5000 next time 10000 ....
I think about batch or chink but I don't know, any help plz.
I've already tried to split the csv file and then try to merge every pieces

```
def split_seq(seq, num_pieces):
    start = 0
    for i in range(num_pieces):
        stop = start + len(seq[i::num_pieces])
        yield seq[start:stop]
        start = stop
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `df.iloc[start:end]` it will give you data chunk between those indexs, take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

you don't have to split your csv file each time, work directly on the dataframe

Comment: this will not give me a equilibrated classes because i'm working with N and P sentiments

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this function. Set the parameters to decide the start position and the batch_size.

```
'''
Parameters:
data - dataframe
batch_size - number of rows/items in a batch
start - batch to start from
Return:
split - batch of dataframe
start - start position for next iteration
'''
def batch(data, batch_size, start = 0):
    rows = data.shape[0]
    end = batch_size * (start + 1)
    if(end < rows):
        split = data.iloc[(batch_size * start):end]
    else:
        split = data.iloc[(batch_size * start):]
    return split, start + 1
```

**Example**

It can be used to split up a dataframe as follows

```
# Dataframe
data = pd.read_csv('./path/file.csv')

# Set parameters
start = 0
batch_size = 3

# Generate batches
while(start <= data.shape[0]//batch_size):
    dt, start = batch(data, batch_size, start)
    print(dt, '\n-----------------------')
```

**Sample output**

```
           Category Name  Unit  Price
0  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     10
1  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     12
2  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     12 
-----------------------
           Category Name  Unit  Price
3  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     20
4  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     23
5  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     25 
-----------------------
           Category Name  Unit  Price
6  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     25
7  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     25
8  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     29 
-----------------------
           Category Name  Unit  Price
9  Leather Safety Gloves  Pair     30 
-----------------------
```

Comment: can i combine it with random state !

Comment: Yes you can. you'll have to maintain the current row position (Should not go out of bounds of the dataframe). To overcome that, you can also use a circular method (end connected to the start).

Comment: can you explain more plz